# How to display coordinates from MySQL and display as a marker in Android Google Maps

Tags: android

Is it possible to load coordinates from MySQL DB and display as markers in Android Google Maps, if its possible can i get source code because i have tried every possible way but it couldn't work at all
Here is my code on java side

```
 private void getMarkers() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("Response: ", response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                String getObject = jObj.getString("data");
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getObject);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    title = jsonObject.getString(TITLE);
                    latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LAT)), Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LNG)));
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    markerOptions.position(latLng)
                            .title(title)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, tag_json_obj);
```

Comment: What did you try? Show us some code

Comment: I have already upload some

Answer (score 0):

Extract your cordinates from database using approriate query then call the `dearwMarker` function like `drawMarker(new LatLng(lat, lng));`

```
private void drawMarker(final LatLng point){
private Marker marker;
marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(point)
        .title("tittle);
```

}